# jQuery function working in IE but need to repeatedly refresh for it to working in Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

The following code is placed just before the closing body tag.  It works everytime in IE 7+, but rarely in Chrome or Firefox without refreshing the page multiple times.  Any ideas what might be causing this? Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.rollOver').each(function() 
    {
        var backgroundImageURL  = $(this).find('.backgroundImage').prop('src');
        var backgroundImageWidth = $(this).find('.backgroundImage').width();
        var backgroundImageHeight = $(this).find('.backgroundImage').height();

        $('.backgroundImage').css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('.rollOverContent').css({'display' : 'none'});

        $(this).css(
        {
            'background' : 'url(' + backgroundImageURL + ') no-repeat', 
            'height' : backgroundImageHeight,
            'width' : backgroundImageWidth
        }); 
    });

    $('.rollOver').hover(function() 
    {
        $(this).find('.rollOverContent').fadeToggle('fast');        
    });

    $('.rollOver').mouseenter(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({'background' : '#1748a7'});
    });

    $('.rollOver').mouseleave(function() 
    {  
        var backgroundImageURL  = $(this).find('.backgroundImage').prop('src');
        $(this).css({'background' : 'url(' + backgroundImageURL + ') no-repeat'});
    });

    $( "#homeTabs" ).tabs({collapsible: true, selected: 2});
});
```

Comment: NITPICK: It is bad practice to use the same selector over and over again becuase it keeps creating jQuery objects and querying the DOM. Store `$(this)` and `$(.rollover')` into variables and reuse the variables. Or use chaining like jQuery is built to do.

Comment: Thanks for responses - I needed the each loop as there could be multiple divs with the class of .rollOver that each need to be effected by the jQuery.

Comment: @Jai, there are no events being bound in the each(), I updated the formatting so it is easier to read.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle of this problem? Often just creating the Fiddle may lead to an answer yourself.

Comment: Possibly it might help to wait until the `.backgroundImage` is loaded before doing things with it. (As the height and width would be 0 when it's not loaded). So maybe wrap an `$('img.backgroundImage').load(function(){..})` around things. If you'd added a fiddle I'd try it myself, but eh  ;)

Comment: Sorry - turns out some other unrelated jQuery function on the page was causing the issue. I wrapped it in document.ready and the jQuery above started working in FF. Not sure why it now works, but it does!